# How to check VALUES from different datasets spatially near with ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geometry, line

I need some suggestions, let's see:

I have two heavy polyline datasets, from different sources, so they will never be coincident (it doesn't matter this issue). **Both have the same field from which I need to work**. These string fields has 3 possible values. So, I need to check if every polyline, which is more or less parallel to the other,  **is coincident in VALUE**.

An example,

We've got 5 labelled (with the Value to check) polylines (3 from one dataset, 2 from the other), in this cases, there is no mistakes, there is concordance. Then I have a 1 polyline (the one with the red cross), with no paired polyline, but this doesn't really care. Just the ones paired mostly parallel.

[image: Example]

Somebody knows any ArcGIS10 tool or some Python code to check it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a first check, you could make a spatial join between the red and the black lines, then see if you have the good attributes as well as an acceptable distance.

EDIT: I realized based on your illustration on another post that several lines were intersecting at some places. Therefore the simple spatial join between lines will not work. You should first use feature vertices to point (MID) in order to have the center point of one of the lines, then you an join with the other set of lines.